Identifying parts of multipart line in QGIS
I have a line (shapefile) with 745 vertices and an aggregate of three parts (multiparts). How can I identify where these multiparts are on the line?
In ArcGIS Pro, each part was simply identified in the Vertices table but is not identified in the QGIS vertices table that I can see, other than to say there are three parts.

You could use the multipart to singlepart tool which creates a temporary layer which you can then use, via selection or symbology, to see where each part is.

For visual clues, you can add a marker line, with a specific symbol on the start of each line part, and why not another marker line with another symbol at the end of each line part.
The example below uses an arrow symbol, which is rotated to follow the line direction AND that are rotated by + or - 90 degrees.

Another "quick and dirty" option is to show an arrow line.

A variant of @eurojam solution would be to set a data override of a simple line color, to define an array of colors and to use a different color for each part being rendered
array_get(array('red','green','blue','orange'), @geometry_part_num -1)


nice variant with the color array

This is also awesome! Thank you so much!

If you don't want to produce a new layer with the processing option mentioned by @John you can even use a style with geometry generator and the following expression:
geometry_n(@geometry,1)

which return the first part - color green in the example below. Second part would be geometry_n(@geometry,2) and so on


Thank you...this is awesome! I tried using that but couldn't figure out the expression (I'm a new user!). Ver helpful!
